# Getting error stating that my if statement is always false, what do i need to do?

Tags: java

So i have been given a task for my degree level programming in Java, the task can be seen below:

My problem is getting errors stating:

- Condition 'a >= 18' is always 'false'

  Condition 'a < 11' is always 'false'

Task

```
1)In a new command line project, write code which will prompt the
user for the age of a young person (between the age of 11 and 18,
and determine the highest category of film they can view at the
cinema unaccompanied. The categories are PG (any age), 12, 15 and 18

2)Add a default clause stating that they are too young to see a film
unaccompanied.

3)Add an 'if' statement to check if the age entered is over 18. If
so, print a message stating that they can see any film they like,
but if the value is under 18, ensure the switch statement is
executed
```

My code can be seen below:

```
package im.ucm.co4025;
```

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your age: ");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    switch (a) {
        case 11 -> System.out.println("You can view up to PG rated films unaccompanied");
        case 12, 13, 14 -> System.out.println("You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied");
        case 15, 16, 17 -> {
            System.out.println("You can view films up to a 15 age rating unaccompanied");


            if (a >= 18) {
                System.out.println("You can watch any film unaccompanied");

            }
            if (a < 11) {
                System.out.println("You are too young to view a film unaccompanied");
            }
        }
    }
    }


}
```

Comment: The if statements should lead to the switch. Not the other way around.

Comment: Im not the best with the java jargin but if i understand what your asking the cases works up until you enter a value below 11 and above 17

Comment: @AlexRudenko: Is this not a [new form of `case` label in Java 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html)?

Comment: @FredLarson, my bad :) still on JDK 11 here

Comment: @Spectric, why not?  `case 1: case 2:` etc. is [valid syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: @Spectric: It appears the OP is using Java 12 or newer. See my comment above, and the link therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code which you must fix.

You can't have **if statements** in a switch. Better move them outside.

Here's what the working example should be:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your age: ");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    if (a >= 18) {
        System.out.println("You can watch any film unaccompanied");

   }else if (a < 11) {
                System.out.println("You are too young to view a film unaccompanied");
            }
    switch (a) {
        case 11:
            System.out.println("You can view up to PG rated films unaccompanied");
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.println("You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied");
            break;
        case 13:
            System.out.println("You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied");
            break;
        case 14:
            System.out.println("You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied");
            break;
        case 15:
            System.out.println("You can view films up to a 15 age rating unaccompanied");
            break;
        case 16:
            System.out.println("You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied");
            break;
        case 17:
            System.out.println("You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied");
            break;

    }
    }


}
```

**Sample I/O**

*Input*

```
12
```

*Output*

```
You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied
```

Comment: May want to be more specific on having if statements in a switch. I.E. you can have them inside a Case, but not as a Case.

Answer (score 1):

The following solutions can be provided:

1. `if` statement to check adult age could be placed outside `switch`
   then `default` in `switch` is referring to minor ages `[0..10].

```java
if (a >= 18) {
    System.out.println("You can watch any film unaccompanied");
} else {
    switch (a) {
        case 11 -> System.out.println("You can view up to PG rated films unaccompanied");
        case 12, 13, 14 -> System.out.println("You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied");
        case 15, 16, 17 -> System.out.println("You can view films up to a 15 age rating unaccompanied");
        default -> System.out.println("You are too young to view a film unaccompanied at the age of " + a);
    }
}
```

2. replace `if` with a ternary operator in the `default`:

```java
switch (a) {
    case 11 -> System.out.println("You can view up to PG rated films unaccompanied");
    case 12, 13, 14 -> System.out.println("You can view films up to a 12 age rating unaccompanied");
    case 15, 16, 17 -> System.out.println("You can view films up to a 15 age rating unaccompanied");
    default -> System.out.println(a >= 18 ? 
        "You can watch any film unaccompanied" : 
        "You are too young to view a film unaccompanied at the age of " + a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this is because the if statements are in the case for 15,16,17.
Thus the only situation where `if(a>=18)` or `if(a<11)` is ran the only possible things `a` could be is 15, 16, or 17.